# Chrome Extension Gapi on Gmail: Gmail attempting people lookup 403

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-api-js-client, google-people-api

I'm working on a chrome extension that uses the google api and gsuite to grab and display emails in their own section of gmail. The problem is when going into emails themselves, both from the main inbox and my view, it(gmail?) tries to run a people lookup at https://people-pa.clients6.google.com/v2/people/lookup and 403s showing a red banner with: 
"Gmail is having authentication problems. Some features may not work. Try  logging in  to fix the problem."

I tried enabling the people api and adding it to my key, same problem.

I found an open issue in the google api javascript library that seems exactly the same, but no responses. https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/issues/608

Any idea on a fix?

Is my instance of gapi overwriting gmails? Is there a way to avoid that and still use my own instance of gapi? Is it possible to just use their instance? I know they didn't intend the javascript client to be used in chrome extensions, so am I just out of luck?

Thanks